# generating completely new vector based on other vectors

Tags: vector, linear-algebra, word2vec

Assume I have four-vectors (v1,v2,v3,v4), and I want to create a new vector (vec_new) that is not close to any of those four-vectors. I was thinking about interpolation and extrapolation. Do you think they are suitable? Are they also apply for vector and generate a vector of let's say 300 dimensions? Another possible option would be the transformation matrix. But I am not sure if it fit my concern. I think averaging and concatenation are not the good ones as I might be close to some of those four-vectors.

based on my problem, Imagine I divided my vectors into two categories. I need to find a vector which belongs to non-of those categories.

Any other ideas?

Comment: when you say that you need vec_new to not be close what do you mean? how close would that be?

Comment: I am considering the cosine similarity as the measurement to find the closeness. So, the highest values are the closest, let's say anything above 60, and the lowest values are the faraway ones, let's say anything below 30. I am wondering to get a vector with the lowest possible value.

Comment: you might want to consider consulting math stackexchange, bc this sounds like a optimization problem, the only thing that would be in programming is the creation of the function that accepts as inputs the four vectors and outputs the best vec_new, which if you know what to do, it could be written in numpy

Comment: In high dimensional spaces, there are many, many possible vectors that are unlike other vectors. So, it'd be useful to know: why do you want a 4th vector that's far away? (It's possible your real need suggests some more specific way to generate another vector.) Also, as cosine-similarity in high-dimensions is typically reported on a `-1.0` to `1.0` range, the least-similar vectors to some other vector/vectors would show a cosine-similarity closest to `-1.0`, not "below 30".

Comment: based on my problem, Imagine I divided my vectors into two categories.  I need to find a vector which belongs to non-of those categories.

Comment: I would not especially expect that approach to be helpful for many realistic goals. High-dimensional spaces are non-intuitive; just being 'far' from known entities wouldn't necessarily tell you anything about any real counterexamples. But, I'll suggest a possible approach to your literal request in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment, I wouldn't expect the creation of synthetic "far away" examples to be useful for realistic goals.

Even things like word antonyms **are not** maximally cosine-dissimilar from each other, because among the realm of all word-meaning-possibilities, antonyms are quite similar to each other. For example, 'hot' and 'cold' are considered opposites, but are the same kind of word, describing the same temperature-property, and can often be drop-in replacements for each other in the same sentences. So while they may show an interesting contrast in word-vector space, the "direction of difference" isn't going to be through the origin -- as would create maximal cosine-dissimilarity.

And in classification contexts, even a simple 2-category classifier will need actual 'negative' examples. With only positive examples, the 'vector space' won't necessarily model anything about hypothesized-but-not-actually-present negative examples. (It's nearly impossible to divide the space into two categories without training examples showing the real "boundaries".)

Still, there's an easy way to make a vector that is maximally dissimilar to another single vector: negate it. That creates a vector that's in the exact opposite direction from the original, and thus will have a cosine-similarity of `-1.0`.

If you have a number of vectors against which you want to find a maximally-dissimilar vector, I suspect you can't do much better than *negating the average of all the vectors*. That is, average the vectors, then negate that average-vector, to find the vector that's pointing exactly-opposite the average.

Good luck!

Comment: Good point, but a small question. In the case of having two categories, the negation of a vector belonging to one category puts you close to the other category vectors. As they might be the potential vectors for the negation, which is not working in my case.

Comment: Negation of a vector puts the new vector on the other side of the origin point (and highly dissimilar by cosine-similarity). But whether that new vector is actually related to some other contrasting category will be very data- and goal-dependent. It might be resoundingly the same category, with any other categories being off in other directions! That's why I wouldn't have high expectations for your "find a very different vector" approach that's not grounded in actual labeled examples.

Comment: To say anything more helpful, I'd need more concrete details of what your data, vectors, and categories are. It sounds like you're trying to improvise some sort of classification system, perhaps with insufficient examples. But if you're starting with text, there's plenty of theory & practice to use, for both feature-engineering & then classification. It usually wouldn't involve trying to find "the other category" via fundamental vector transformations, without the advantage of many tangible, contrasting examples of both categories.

Comment: (It's not completely unheard-of -- eg: 'One Class Classification' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification, But that's a murkier matter than usual 2-category supervised text classification problems.)

Comment: I am trying to deteriorate the output of the classifier. I have some text data that I have collected from Twitter. I have categorized the data into recent and old posts. I used word2vec to change twitter posts to vectors, the summation of words appears in the post. So in my example, imagine v1,v2 are the posts vector belong to the recent category, and v3,v4 to the old category. I am trying to create some noised vectors which are far away or in the middle of both categories (nature: neither in old nor in current category).

Comment: That helps, but why would such synthetic vectors, unassociated w/ any real text or time-era, be useful? A classifier's performance on them is not-evaluable - any prediction/confidence it reports can't be said to be right or wrong. Also, such vectors may not correspond to any potential real text or time-period. (High-dimensional word-vector spaces aren't necessarily balanced around the origin, or equally dense with words in all regions... so such manufactured vectors could be in low-meaning/low-resolution "dead zones", & any derived analysis – such as nearest-other-words – could be low-value.)

Comment: Yes, correct. I have to generate these dead zone intentionally low-resolution vectors to deteriorate the output of the classifier.

Comment: OK, but I'm not sure that's a sound strategy. The classifier's answer to synthetic points of unknown (but distant) words may not be right, wrong, or anything else. Good luck!